# What are the main deference between Build bundle vs Generate Signed bundle apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build, signed

What are the main deference between Build bundle vs Generate Signed bundle android studio.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Build Bundle

When you normally run your application, an APK file is generated locally which is like a ZIP file and is easily unzippable, no security is implemented, and you can get the code from that APK file. It is used basically for local testing.

### Signed apk

It is that APK you can create with a password and security and it is not easily unzippable and is used for production.

Comment: That is a generic explanation about signing an apk. It does not explain the difference between the two options in Android Studio menu. AFAIU the "Build bundle" option does not necessarily mean "Build unsigned bundle".

Answer (score 6):

Muhammad's point about the `Build Bundle / APK` feature isn't entirely true.

For example, if you have a `release` signing config that is used by your `prod` product flavor, and you select the `prodRelease` variant as active variant in Android Studio and then click the `Build Bundle / APK` button, then Gradle will generate a **signed** `prod` build using your `release` signing config. The same happens when you click the `Run 'app'` button (the green ▶ icon).

The only real difference I see is that the `Build Bundle / APK` generates a build using the **current active variant** that you've selected in Android Studio and the signing config associated to it in the gradle file, whereas the `Generate Signed Bundle / APK...` button allows you to build **any variant with any signing config**, even one that is not in the gradle file.